# to upload my php page in a free domain?

Tags: php, web-hosting

I had created some sample webpages in php and i need to know how to upload these pages in a server with free domain.

i like to use my pages in real time server. i didnt had any domain. is there any free service for exposing my page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out:

- [Kodingen](http://kodingen.com/)

[View screencast for more](http://www.screencast.com/users/devrim/folders/Jing/media/75cd28a5-7aae-4923-9b15-27ab26175796)

Comment: How to use i created an account. How to upload my files and how can i test this

Comment: @Mohan Ram: I can't write here, you should now go their and see the support/help for more information :)